# Using $inc to increment a document property with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to increment the `views` count by 1 each time my document is accessed. So far, my code is:

```
Document
    .find({})
    .sort('date', -1)
    .limit(limit)
    .exec();
```

Where does `$inc` fit in here?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Never used mongoose but quickly looking over the docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/finding-documents.html) it seems like this will work for you:

```
# create query conditions and update variables
var conditions = { },
    update = { $inc: { views: 1 }};

# update documents matching condition
Model.update(conditions, update).limit(limit).sort('date', -1).exec();
```

Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 8):

I ran into another problem, which is kind of related to $inc.. So I'll post it here as it might help somebody else. I have the following code:

```
var Schema = require('models/schema.js');

var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.increase = function(id, key, amount, callback){
   Schema.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $inc: { key: amount }}, function(err, data){
      //error handling
   }
}
```

from a different module I would call something like

```
var saver = require('./saver.js');

saver.increase('555f49f1f9e81ecaf14f4748', 'counter', 1, function(err,data){
    //error handling
}
```

However, this would not increase the desired counter. Apparently it is not allowed to directly pass the key into the update object. This has something to do with the syntax for string literals in object field names. The solution was to define the update object like this:

```
exports.increase = function(id, key, amount, callback){

   var update = {};
   update['$inc'] = {};
   update['$inc'][key] = amount;

   Schema.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, function(err, data){
      //error handling
   }
}
```

Comment: The bug in the first version of your code is this: `{ $inc: { key: amount }}`. You're not actually using the `key` variable there, but making the object key the string `"key"`. The correct way to write this code is  `{ $inc: { [key]: amount }}`, using [ES2015 computed property keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (mongoose 5.7)

```js
blogRouter.put("/:id", async (request, response) => {
 try {
  const updatedBlog = await Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(
   request.params.id,
   {
    $inc: { likes: 1 }
   },
   { new: true } //to return the new document
  );
  response.json(updatedBlog);
 } catch (error) {
  response.status(400).end();
 }
});
```