# How do I increment a Number value in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

People of StackOverflow, I am burning with the question, how do I increment a
Number value in Mongoose? I have tried the code below, though it is not working. I am trying to increment a value by one on the submission of a form. Below is my code:

```
app.post('/like', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.body.id;
    var query = {_id: id};
    var post = Meme.findOne(query);
    Meme.findOneAndUpdate(post, post.likes: post.likes+1)
});
```

Thanks so much for your valuable help!

Comment: you can try something like this `Meme.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $inc: { "post.likes": 1 } })`. Not tested.

Comment: Are you getting the data in your `post` variable? Please put a `console` statement and check whether data is coming or not.

Comment: @Safal_R_Aryal you can also refer this question for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621948/doing-inc-with-mongoose Thanks!

Answer (score 125):

You can use `$inc` for this purpose.

**Try this:**

```
var id = req.body.id;
Meme.findOneAndUpdate({_id :id}, {$inc : {'post.likes' : 1}}).exec(...);
```

For more info on $inc, Please read [MongoDB $inc documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)

Comment: also works if you want to reduce: just give a negative number like so:var id = req.body.id;
Meme.findOneAndUpdate({_id :id}, {$inc : {'post.likes' : -1}}).exec(...);

Answer (score 11):

With mongoose version 5 an additional option "useFindAndModify" is needed:

```
 // Make Mongoose use mongoDB's `findOneAndUpdate()`. Note that this option is `true`
 // by default, you need to set it to false.
 mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);


 Meme.findOneAndUpdate( {_id: res._id}, 
      {$inc : {'UID' : 1}}, 
      {new: true}, 
      function(err, response) { 
           // do something
      });
```

[Mongoose Depreciation Doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-)

Answer (score 5):

```
Meme.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: res._id }, { $inc: {'post.like': 1 } }, {new: true },function(err, response) {
 if (err) {
 callback(err);
} else {
 callback(response);
}
```

[Hope this link help to find your solution](https://medium.com/@salonimalhotra1ind/how-to-increment-a-number-value-in-mongoose-785066ba09d8)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this, I used this query to like the post

```
app.put('/like', (req, res) => {
    Meme.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.postId,{
    $push:{likes: req.user._id}
    }, {
        new: true
    }).exec((err, result) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({error: err})
        }else{
            res.json(result)
        }
    })
})
```